# Check if key value pairs are unique before posting to redis instance

Tags: python, django, redis

I am `POST`ing a list of key values pairs to a `redis_instance`. I would like to first check if any of the keys/values I am posting to redis already exist to avoid having duplicate key value pairs or instances where a pre-existing key has a different value or a pre-existing value has a different key so for example avoiding scenarios like this:

```
Fred: Luke
Luke: Jim
Jim: Jane
```

and instead only allow these pairs to be written to my `redis_instance`:

```
Fred: Luke
Jim: Jane
```

This is what I have:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_items(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = {}
        count = 0
        for key in redis_instance.keys("*"):
            items[key.decode("utf-8")] = redis_instance.get(key)
            count += 1
        response = {
            'count': count,
            'msg': f"Found {count} items.",
            'items': items
        }
        return Response(response, status=200)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        item = json.loads(request.body)
        keys = list(item.keys())
        values = list(item.values())
        for i in range(0, len(keys)):
            redis_instance.set(keys[i], values[i])
        response = {
            'msg': f"{keys} successfully set to {values}"
        }
        return Response(response, 201)
```

not quite sure how to carry this out

Comment: What library are you using to talk with `redis`? Which type is your `redis_instance` variable?

Comment: Should existing keys or values just be skipped? Or should existing key updated to the new value? And if yes, how to handle existing values with a different key?

Comment: @JanMalte to answer your second question, existing keys/values should be skipped. I am using `django redis`